# Sliding window with no overlap

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Implementing a sliding window I've written this :

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class PreProcess {

    public static <T> Stream<List<T>> createSlidingWindow(List<T> list, int size) {
        if(size > list.size())
            return Stream.empty();
        return IntStream.range(0, list.size()-size+1)
                .mapToObj(start -> list.subList(start, start+size));
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
        Stream<List<Integer>> sw = createSlidingWindow(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4 ,5) , 3);
        sw.forEach(x -> {
            System.out.println(x);
        });
    }

}
```

Executing this code prints:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 4, 5]
```

I'm attempting to modify so that there is no overlap between each window so a sliding window of size 3 will return:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5]
```

I think I need to modify `start` so that it's pointing to the next window but I'm unsure how to do achieve this using streams.

Comment: did you rather mean sublists/partitions instead of sliding windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
public static <T> Stream<List<T>> createSlidingWindow(List<T> list, int size) {
    return IntStream.range(0, list.size())
            .mapToObj(i -> list.subList(
                    Math.min(list.size(), size * i),
                    Math.min(list.size(), size + (size * i))))
            .filter(l -> !l.isEmpty());
}
```

`IntStream#range(int, int)` assures an ordered sequence of numbers from the left `int` to the right one (exclusive) for iterating the index. The subsequent `mapToObj` uses `List#subList(int, int)` to define chunks or partitions from the original list depending on the current pivot (`i`) position in the "loop". Here is the output:

> ```
> [1, 2, 3]
> [4, 5]
> ```

My algorithm is not the most effective/neat since you need to filter out the empty chunks using `.filter(l -> !l.isEmpty())` however, *you have the idea* and let the little modification be up to you.